# Zend Framework params plugin not retrieving post params

Tags: php, angularjs, zend-framework2

I'm extending the `AbstractRestfulController` and attemping to post data to my `create` function, but when I try and receive the data using the params plugin I get an empty array:

```
public function create() {
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
        return new JsonModel(array('data' => $data));
 }
```

I successfully post from my angular `$resource` with the save function and get this back:

```
{"data":[]}
```

Any ideas why the params plugin is not getting the parameters? Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `create()` function has to have the `$data` variable specified in the argument list:

```
public function create($data) {
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
        return new JsonModel(array('data' => $data));
 }
```

It seems like the framework then passes in the `$_POST` superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$this->params()->fromPost()` you should be using this in an Action.

Example:

```
public function createAction()
{
    $data = $this->params()->fromPost();

    return new JsonModel(array('data' => $data));
}
```

Currently you are only using a standard function name which isn't being parsed. So in this case you'd need to pass the POSTed data to that function `$this->create($data);`

Comment: The documentation for the AbstractRestfulController states that the HTTP verbs get routed to the specific functions. It also states that the create function expects a $data variable to be passed in, but it's no clear on how.
From the documentation:
"POST maps to create(). That method expects a $data argument, usually the $_POST superglobal array."
Does that mean that it will pass in the $_POST superglobal?

Comment: Ok, more testing, that seems like the case. If you specify $data as the function argument it passes in the $_POST superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to be sent to the server?

Angular sends everything as raw JSON (mimetype application/json), not application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Therefore it won't be in `$_POST`, instead you can get at it by:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Perhaps your Framework has an easier way.

Comment: The Zend Framework looks for a `Content-Type` header for `application/json` and automatically parses the JSON, if the JSON is incorrect it throws an error. Angular provides this header.